# What is the best practice for reservation flow in hotel reservation system to handle concurrency for multiple reservation?

Tags: java, mysql, concurrency, race-condition, spring-transactions

For my college project, I'm developing a hotel reservation application using Java along with the Spring framework and MySQL database.

## Database details:

- I have an entity type that stores reservations details

**reservation**

| reservation-id | check-in | check-out | .. all other details |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

- when user wants to reserve rooms, I use this table to transactionally check in database that all rooms are available and if so, reserve them and add new entity in the table.

I need to know how the flow of reservation should work.

## **I thought about 2 scenarios:**

**first scenario**: user selects the rooms he wants to reserve -> check out and enter his credit card number -> transactional check in database occurs. if rooms aren't available, I will tell the user that the rooms are not available, else I will proceed with payment.

my Question here is it normal to let the user enter his credit card and then tell him sorry the rooms are not available?

**second scenario:**

- I will add another entity type called temporarily reservation that have reservation-id as a foreign key and expiration date-attribute that refers to

**temporarily reservation**

| reservation-id (foreign key) | expiration-date |
| --- | --- |

user selects the rooms he wants to reserve -> transactional check in database occurs. if all rooms are available, reserve them in both "temporarily reservation" and "reservation" tables -> let the user enter his credit card number -> if payment is successful, delete the reservation from "temporarily reservation" table else if any error occurs during payment, delete reservation from both tables.
the problem is when the user doesn't enter his credit card or closes the application before confirming payment. So, I will use the "temporarily reservation" table and scheduled function that runs periodically to remove all expired unconfirmed reservations from both tables.

I know this solution might not be practical, so I want to know how this problem is actually solved.

Answer (score 2):

Your first approach, if you think in real world practical way, is not very good and from User Experience Design perspective its very bad, since you are making user to do all the hard work and then you say that the room is not available is not very good User Experience.

You should take the room and checkin/checkout details first before payment and check whether you have room availability or not for that day and that time. If you have then apply the below logic and proceed with taking payment details.

One way to solve this problem, is as someone is in middle of transaction you apply a lock on the room for the particular day and check-in/checkout time, and keep that lock for maybe 10 mins, this much time is enough for the user to do the payment transaction and book room, otherwise delete the lock from the database table and let others book the room.

In this way, you solve your reservation problem by applying temporary lock while the transaction is going on for some defined time, if the transaction is complete you book the room. If the transaction fails, remove the temporary lock.

Comment: "...you apply a lock on the room [and] day...for maybe 10 mins." FWIW: Another name for that temporary lock is a "_hold._"